# ADB needs root after upgrading to Android 5.1.1

Tags: android, udev, nexus-7, adb

I am building Android from source in order to install my company's custom filesystem (Datalight Reliance Nitro). I'm using an Ubuntu 12.04 PC as my host device and a Nexus 7 (flo) as my Android device. I have followed [the instructions](https://source.android.com/source/initializing.html) for setting up the the host system, including setting up the file /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules.

I had been building Android 4.4.3, and ADB ran just fine as expected. (No need for sudo privileges.)

However, when I built and installed Android 5.1.1, suddenly ADB complains:

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached 
????????????    no permissions
```

I tried several further mods to my 51-android.rules file, but no success. Following [CyanogenMod's instructions on the topic](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/UDEV), I finally ran the ADB server on sudo, and that worked. But I'm wondering why. How could the version of Android effect the privileges ADB needs? Or am I possibly overlooking something else entirely?

Answer (score 0):

You need add your device id to the rules.
Plug your device through usb.
Make `lsusb` and look for your device.
You'll receive something like

```
Bus 003 Device 048: ID 18d1:4ee7 Google Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Then add line in /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules similar to others but with idVendor (in this example '18d1'), and idProduct (here '4ee7')

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="18d1", ATTR{idProduct}=="4ee7", MODE="0600", OWNER="{same as others}"
```

then

```
sudo udevadm control --reload-rules
```